# c# json serialize with attributes

Tags: c#, json, serialization, netflix-eureka

I like to write a .net connector to Eureka register service using rest api. It asks for a json format as below and would like to generate that json from configuration class. Could not find out how to serialize some properties like attributes which looks like $, and @ at the beginnnig in the json like         "securePort": {"$": "8443", "@enabled": "true"},

the json needed for eureka:

```
{
    "instance": {
        "hostName": "WKS-SOF-L011",
        "app": "com.automationrhapsody.eureka.app",
        "vipAddress": "com.automationrhapsody.eureka.app",
        "secureVipAddress": "com.automationrhapsody.eureka.app"
        "ipAddr": "10.0.0.10",
        "status": "STARTING",
        "port": {"$": "8080", "@enabled": "true"},
        "securePort": {"$": "8443", "@enabled": "true"},
        "healthCheckUrl": "http://WKS-SOF-L011:8080/healthcheck",
        "statusPageUrl": "http://WKS-SOF-L011:8080/status",
        "homePageUrl": "http://WKS-SOF-L011:8080",
        "dataCenterInfo": {
            "@class": "com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo", 
            "name": "MyOwn"
        },
    }
}
```

my class thats expected generate the json below after serialization(i use newtonsoft.json):

```
public class Port
{
    public string PortName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("enabled")]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public class DataCenterInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("class")]
    public string Class { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EurekaRegisterParams
{
    [JsonProperty("instanceId")]
    public string InstanceId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("hostName")]
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("app")]
    public string App { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ipAddr")]
    public string IpAddr { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("port")]
    public Port Port { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("securePort")]
    public Port SecurePort { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("countryId")]
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dataCenterInfo")]
    public DataCenterInfo DataCenterInfo { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("homePageUrl")]
    public string HomePageUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("statusPageUrl")]
    public string StatusPageUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("healthCheckUrl")]
    public string HealthCheckUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did you try after adding `[JsonProperty("$")]` to `PortName` property in `Port` entity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close to the solution. You could use the `JsonProperty` attribute to do your job as you have already done with the rest of the properties.

```
public class Port
{
    [JsonProperty("$")]
    public string PortName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@enabled")]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```